# pandas - apply replace function with condition row-wise

Tags: python, pandas

Starting with this dataframe `df`:

```
     0     1     2
02  en    it  None
03  en  None  None
01  nl    en   fil
```

There are some missing values. I'm trying to apply a replace function row-wise, e.g. in pseudocode:

```
def replace(x):
    if 'fil' and 'nl' in row:
        x = ''
```

I know that I can do someting like:

```
df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

with a function `f` defined like:

```
def f(x):
    if x[0] == 'nl' and x[2] == 'fil':
        x[0] = ''
    return x
```

obtaining:

```
     0     1     2
02  en    it  None
03  en  None  None
01        en   fil
```

but a priori I don't know the actual positions of the strings through the columns, so I have to search with something like the `isin` method, but row-wise.

EDIT: every string can appear anywhere throughout the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Boolean Indexing and Text Comparison in Pandas

You could create [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) based on [string comparisons](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#testing-for-strings-that-match-or-contain-a-pattern) like this

```
df['0'].str.contains('nl') & df['2'].str.contains('fil')
```

or since you updated that the columns could change:

```
df.isin(['fil']).any(axis=1) & df.isin(['nl']).any(axis=1)
```

Here is the test case:

```
import pandas as pd
from cStringIO import StringIO

text_file = '''
     0     1     2
02  en    it  None
03  en  None  None
01  nl    en   fil
'''

# Read in tabular data
df = pd.read_table(StringIO(text_file), sep='\s+')
print 'Original Data:'
print df
print

# Create boolean index based on text comparison
boolIndx = df.isin(['nl']).any(axis=1) & df.isin(['fil']).any(axis=1)
print 'Example Boolean index:'
print boolIndx
print

# Replace string based on boolean assignment   
df.loc[boolIndx] = df.loc[boolIndx].replace('nl', '')
print 'Filtered Data:'
print df
print
```

---

```
Original Data:
    0     1     2
2  en    it  None
3  en  None  None
1  nl    en   fil

Example Boolean index:
2    False
3    False
1     True
dtype: bool

Filtered Data:
    0     1     2
2  en    it  None
3  en  None  None
1        en   fil
```

Comment: Thank you.  Tried to also provide links for you and future viewers if one needs to dig into specific details.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```
In [111]:
def func(x):
    return x.isin(['fil']).any() &  x.isin(['nl']).any()
df.loc[df.apply(func, axis=1)] = df.replace('nl','')
df

Out[111]:
    0     1     2
2  en    it  None
3  en  None  None
1        en   fil
```

So the function will return `True` if both values are present in the row in any position:

```
In [107]:
df.apply(func, axis=1)

Out[107]:
2    False
3    False
1     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks, actually I don't want to overwrite all the values in the first column, only change the value of the row and the column where the condition is satisfied (e.g. the `en` value in the first two rows should stay there...).

Comment: Thanks! Sorry there are still some typos to fix, the assignment function should be now written as: `df.loc[df.apply(func, axis=1)] = df.replace('nl','')`.

Comment: So the 'nl' can appear anywhere rather than the first col?

Comment: yes, anywhere, and I have to look at its position and then replace its value with ' ', but with `df.loc[df.apply(func, axis=1)] = df.replace('nl','')` should work correctly.

Comment: @FabioLamanna may I recommend that you shouldn't use the `apply` function if you don't have to, just use the boolean index directly, see my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36033682/2087463) for how.

Comment: @tmthydvnprt yes thanks, I know that `apply` is not fast with huge dataframes.

Comment: @FabioLamanna the assignment is now column independent as well